# Why would g++ be unable to find system includes which are installed?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

Here's a simple example program which compiles on my desktop linux machine (Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit intel, fwiw):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  cout<<"hello"<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it on an embedded machine which appears to have the header files (and the equivalent of build-essential) installed:

```
me@t4240rdb:~$ ls /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/iostream
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/iostream
me@t4240rdb:~# find /usr/include/ -name cmath
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/ext/cmath
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/cmath
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/tr1/cmath
```

using `g++ /home/me/tc.cpp`, I get

```
/home/me/tc.cpp:1:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

Anyone have any idea why this would happen?

Including the output of g++ -v as requested in the comments:

```
me@t4240rdb:~# g++ -v /home/me/tc.cpp 
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib64/gcc/gcc/powerpc64-fsl-linux/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: powerpc64-fsl-linux
Configured with: /home/jenkins/ci/iso-make/master/b4860qds-64b/build_b4860qds-64b/tmp/work-shared/gcc-4.9.2-r0/gcc-4.9.2/configure --build=x86_64-linux --host=powerpc64-fsl-linux --target=powerpc64-fsl-linux --prefix=/usr --exec_prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/usr/lib64/gcc --datadir=/usr/share --sysconfdir=/etc --sharedstatedir=/com --localstatedir=/var --libdir=/usr/lib64 --includedir=/usr/include --oldincludedir=/usr/include --infodir=/usr/share/info --mandir=/usr/share/man --disable-silent-rules --disable-dependency-tracking --with-libtool-sysroot=/home/jenkins/ci/iso-make/master/b4860qds-64b/build_b4860qds-64b/tmp/sysroots/b4860qds-64b --with-gnu-ld --enable-shared --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-threads=posix --enable-multilib --enable-c99 --enable-long-long --enable-symvers=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-pch --program-prefix=powerpc64-fsl-linux- --without-local-prefix --enable-target-optspace --enable-lto --enable-libssp --disable-bootstrap --disable-libmudflap --with-system-zlib --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-linker-build-id --with-ppl=no --enable-checking=release --enable-cheaders=c_global --with-sysroot=/ --with-build-sysroot=/home/jenkins/ci/iso-make/master/b4860qds-64b/build_b4860qds-64b/tmp/sysroots/b4860qds-64b --with-native-system-header-dir=/home/jenkins/ci/iso-make/master/b4860qds-64b/build_b4860qds-64b/tmp/sysroots/b4860qds-64b/usr/include --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9.2 --with-long-double-128 --enable-nls --enable-__cxa_atexit
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc'
 /usr/lib64/gcc/gcc/powerpc64-fsl-linux/4.9.2/cc1plus -quiet -v -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__unix__ -D__gnu_linux__ -D__linux__ -Dunix -D__unix -Dlinux -D__linux -Asystem=linux -Asystem=unix -Asystem=posix /home/me/tc.cpp -quiet -dumpbase tc.cpp -auxbase tc -version -o /tmp/cc4avGfH.s
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.9.2 (powerpc64-fsl-linux)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.9.2, GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "usr/include/c++/4.9.2"
ignoring nonexistent directory "usr/include/c++/4.9.2/powerpc64-fsl-linux"
ignoring nonexistent directory "usr/include/c++/4.9.2/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib64/gcc/powerpc64-fsl-linux/4.9.2/../../../../powerpc64-fsl-linux/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib64/gcc/powerpc64-fsl-linux/4.9.2/include
 /usr/lib64/gcc/powerpc64-fsl-linux/4.9.2/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.9.2 (powerpc64-fsl-linux)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.9.2, GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 63db6eac369c397424f29967693724f9
/home/me/tc.cpp:1:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

It's quite interesting -- there's clearly something wrong with the configuration.  How do I fix it?

Comment: Try `g++ -v /home/me/tc.cpp` - and post the output from that in your question, as it's usually unreadable [and probably too long] for a comment.

Comment: I updated your tags, as I'm 99% sure it's not specific to 4.9 [I'm using 4.9 on my Ubuntu machine at work, and I'm fairly sure that's what my home machine has too, but I mostly use clang at home]

Comment: Your output gives you the error: `#include <...> search starts here: ...` and none of those paths are where your `iostream` is located. It further states that "`usr/include/c++/4.9.2`" is nonexistent.  You will need to update those paths to be `/usr/include/c++/4.9.2` (make sure to include the leading forward slash).

Comment: I totally get that -- I just a) don't know how to do that and b) am wondering why the vendors' SDK built an image with this problem.  I will of course take "b" up with vendor... :-)

Comment: I'm totally willing to RTFM but the FM for g++ is quite large -- a pointer to the right section would be a big help.

Comment: The headers are supposed to be in `/usr/lib64/gcc/powerpc64-fsl-linux/4.9.2/include`  . If that path doesn't exist then you need to find out why.  I suggest *not* linking/copying it to /usr/include (well, not unless you exhausted other options), those could be headers for a different compiler or different version of compiler leading to weird problems down the track.

Comment: I would 1) reinstall g++ (`sudo apt-get install gcc`) or 2) rerun the configure script for `g++` (`./configure`) or 3) both. When it comes to g++ configuration, it can be brutal and sometimes the best/fastest way to resolve it is to just clean it all.

Comment: I tried re-installing the whole system, and retried the build; this failed.  I then set up the "smart" package manager and tried to re-install the gcc package.  I have the rpms from the sdk visible via lighttpd, according to the smart documentation, I added the channels and did a "smart update" -- and smart reported downloading the repo information.  But when I try to re-install gcc using smart, smart says "not available for download.".  So now I'm debugging smart... sigh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turns out to be a bug in gcc, where configuring it with sysroot set to '/' causes exactly this problem.  It was discovered in gcc 4.7.2 and is still broken in gcc 4.9.2.  I have a patch which fixes the problem, and have moved on to trying to understand how to get bitbake to rebuild the target gcc with the patch, so I'm going to answer this.

Here's email regard the bug and patch: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2012-02/msg00320.html